# Unable to delete VM instance. Delete button is disabled

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am unable to delete a VM. Below is the machine type:

```
f1-micro (1 vCPU, 0.6 GB memory)
```

Note:- Delete button is disabled for me. Hence I can't delete it.

Below is error that I get from cloud shell:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.delete) Could not fetch resource:
 - Invalid resource usage: 'Resource cannot be deleted if it's protected against deletion.'.
```

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preventing-accidental-vm-deletion

Comment: Fyi a related issue, VMs belonging to a dataproc job also seem to require you to delete them via dataproc

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like you have enabled deletion protection in Google Cloud Platform.
To check this go to;
Computer Engine > [VM instances](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances), and then click on the instance you are having the issue with.

Up the top click the edit button > scroll down the page a little bit to Deletion protection, make sure it is unticked:

[image]

if it is ticked untick it then scroll to the bottom of the page and save.

Now try deleting it again.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a link to the answer from google cloud documentation in case you would like to see it.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preventing-accidental-vm-deletion#toggling_deletion_protection_for_existing_instances